# How to make Appbar content not stretch to sides on larger displays

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, appbar

I would like to center my `Appbar` content, so it doesn't spread to sides of the screen when on larger displays. There are [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnOgH.jpg) of how it looks like vs how I would like it to look.

The thing is that on smaller screens, both the `Appbar` and page content fits right into the screen, but on larger displays, `Appbar` content continues to spread, while page content stays centered. So I would like the `Appbar` to stay fullwidth while its content stays on same place as page content - as you can see in second screen.

My page code:

```
<Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
  <CssBaseline />
  <AppBar
    position="fixed"
    sx={{
      marginTop: "10px",
      width: `100%`,
    }}
  >
    <Toolbar>
      <IconButton
        color="inherit"
        aria-label="open drawer"
        edge="start"
        sx={{ mr: 2, display: { sm: "none" } }}
      >
        <MenuIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <Box
        sx={{
          borderBottom: 1,
          borderColor: "divider",
          mr: 2,
          display: { xs: "none", sm: "block", md: "block" },
        }}
      >
        <Tabs
          aria-label="basic tabs example"
          TabIndicatorProps={{
            style: {
              background: "#ffffff",
            },
          }}
        >
         // MY TABS 
        </Tabs>
      </Box>
      <div className={classes.alignRight}>
        <IconButton
          color="inherit"
          aria-label="open drawer"
          edge="right"
        >
          <LogoutRoundedIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </div>
    </Toolbar>
  </AppBar>
  <Box
    component="nav"
    sx={{ width: { sm: 0 }, flexShrink: { sm: 0 } }}
    aria-label="mailbox folders"
  >
  </Box>
  {/* Page content */}
  <Box
    component="main"
    sx={{
      flexGrow: 1,
      p: 3,
    }}
  >
    // MY CONTENT
  </Box>
</Box>
```

Changing `Appbar` position tag to `position="static"` changes it to desired width, but I want only the content of that width.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<AppBar position="static">
  <Toolbar
    sx={{
      width: "100%",
      maxWidth: 600,
      mx: "auto"
    }}
  >
```

- Set a `maxWidth` to restrict the width on large screen
- Set `width` to `100%` to expand the content width within the `maxWidth` limit above.
- Set `margin` left and right to `auto` to center the `Toolbar` itself inside the `Appbar`

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Keeping Appbar position="fixed" in combination with maxWidth on Toolbar did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `width` of your `Appbar` is set to 100% — meaning that it would occupy all the space of its flexed parent element `Box`, you need to give it a fixed width or set a maximum limit how much it can stretch.

Here are some suggestions that could fix your problem:

- Giving your `Appbar` a fixed width for each Media query, so that it doesn't extend depending on your screen size.
- Giving your `Appbar` a dynamic width combined with an offset such as `width=calc(75vw + 2rem)`, note that the `75vw` can be substituted for 75% since the parent component takes up 100% of the width view.
- Using `justifyContent : "space-around"` on your `Box` parent component, to achieve the desired result.

Edit: ***NearHuscarl***'s solution seems better.