# Toolbar container to observe minWidth

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to react and material UI and I've been trying to design my navbar so that my logo, search bar and drawer are in the center. I was able to get help earlier to get space between the components and have my search bar centered, but now i'm struggling to have my logo and drawer to be in the center while observing a minimum width from my searchbar.

I already tried wrapping them into a container with a specified width but they lose their alignment in the center.

here's my code:

```
const Search = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  position: 'relative',
  borderRadius: 30,
  backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
  },
  // marginLeft: 10,
 width: 'auto'
}));

const SearchIconWrapper = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 2),
  height: '100%',
  position: 'absolute',
  pointerEvents: 'none',
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
}));

const StyledInputBase = styled(InputBase)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: 'inherit',
  '& .MuiInputBase-input': {
    padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 0),
    // vertical padding + font size from searchIcon
    paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)})`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width'),
    width: 'auto',

  },
}));

export default function SearchAppBar({ search, setSearch }) {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <AppBar position="fixed" sx={{ backgroundColor: "#55597d" }}>
        <Toolbar sx={{ justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
          <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center">
            <img
              style={{ marginRight: "10px" }}
              src={logo}
              alt="logo"
              className="logotext"
              width="38"
              height="38"
            />
          </Stack>
          <Search>
            <SearchIconWrapper>
              <SearchIcon />
            </SearchIconWrapper>
            <StyledInputBase
              sx={{ width: "auto" }}
              value={search}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setSearch(e.target.value);
              }}
              placeholder="Search All Games…"
              inputProps={{ "aria-label": "search" }}
            />
          </Search>
          {/*</div>*/}
          <IconButton
            size="large"
            edge="start"
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            sx={{ mr: 0, ml: 0 }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[image: What I want to achieve]

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69561454/9449426) what you want?

Comment: Yes! You are legend thank you!